# Design screen disappeared in Android studio 2.2

Tags: android, android-studio-2.2, android-constraintlayout

Recently I was playing with `ConstraintLayout` introduced in Android Studio 2.2 preview.

[image]

Screen was like above, but suddenly I have pressed few keys and that black screen disappears.

[image]

Does anyone have any idea about how to get back the design screen?

Comment: There are many bugs in AS 2.2.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are 2 buttons in the bar above that screen

[image]

The one selected here toggles the design, the one to the right (the blue grid) toggles the blueprint.

So in your case click the Show Design button to make it reappear.

If your Android Studio window is too small, these buttons will auto-hide, so if you can't see them make sure that your window is big enough.

---

N.B.: if both screens are visible and you click Show Design, it will hide the blueprint, and vice versa. This may be a bug.